# How to move build artifact into current working directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to find a way how to copy all the files from my artifact folder to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` .

[image]

right now i was only able to move it using absolute path from the logs but you must agree its not the cleanest way to do it.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
     SourceFolder: '/home/vsts/work/1/BuildPipeline/drop/'
     Contents: '**'
     TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

I tried to use `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` variable but when I use it I end up on `/home/vsts/work/1/a`.

can you recommend a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Agent.BuildDirectory` which point to: `/home/vsts/work/1`.

So:

```
SourceFolder: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/BuildPipeline/drop/'
```

Comment: thanks man this actually worked pretty well for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `powershell` task to copy recursively the files:

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: copy items to current working directory
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'Copy-Item -Path "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)\drop\*" -Destination "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" -Recurse'
```